# modify variable from previous object spread

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say we have this:

```
interface Seed {
   val: number
}
```

and we can accept an argument:

```
const incrementSeedVal = (v: Seed) : Seed => {
  return {...v, ...{val: v.val + 1}}
}
```

I am looking for a way to make this even more concise. Maybe I am imagining things, but isn't there even better shorthand for this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Two</s> *Three* alternatives:

```js
const incrementSeedVal = (v: Seed): Seed => {
  return {
    ...v,
    val: v.val + 1
  }
}
```

or

```js
const incrementSeedVal = ({ val, ...rest }: Seed): Seed => {
  return {
    ...rest,
    val: val + 1
  }
}
```

or

```js
const incrementSeedVal = ({ val, ...rest }: Seed): Seed => ({
  ...rest,
  val: val + 1
})
```

FWIW: declaring functions without using the `function` keyword is foolhardy. (This is my own advice and I don't expect other SOers to agree.) All it does is shut off function hoisting, which means you suddenly have to care about the order in which these tools are declared. There is zero value in taking a situation in which there are no wrong answers and converting it to a situation in which there *are* wrong answers. Make it as easy as possible to succeed and as hard as possible to fail. Use `function` to declare functions whenever you can. Nobody cares about "coolness points."

---

Here's a refactor that shrinks `incrementSeedVal` by refactoring into a generalized "increment a single named property":

```js
const incrementSeedVal = incrementProp('val')

function incrementProp( propName ) {
  return ( obj ) => ({ ...obj, [propName]: obj[propName] + 1 })
}

const incrementSeedAge = incrementProp('age')
const incrementSeedTTY = incrementProp('tty')
// etc.
```

It might be valuable if you're creating a whole family of functions like `incrementSeedVal`. But if you only need the one function, this is actually worse (IMHO) because it adds complexity where none is needed. (Keeping complexity under control is an important goal that often gets discarded when people take DRY to its logical, insane, extreme.)

Comment: Or either without the explicit return

Comment: Function hoisting does 100% solve the problem of definition order.

Comment: I stand mistaken :) for some reason I thought it only declared the variable/func without defining it, or something

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to avoid `val: val + 1` more academic than practical but curious

Comment: I hear you. I believe there is not. You can't modify a value while destructuring, nor while using the ES6 property shorthand, nor as part of rest/spread.